# Possible to write move_base plugin in Python?

Tags: python, navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I'd like to write simple global and local planner plugins for move_base. Is it possible to do that in Python? Or do they have to be written in C++? Is there any documentation about this? Tutorials? Anything besides already existing planners?

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174067/possible-to-write-move_base-plugin-in-python?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2014-06-19

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The planners are loaded into move_base using [pluginlib](http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib), which is entirely C++ and does not have Python capabilities. However, you could possibly use Boost::Python capabilities to embed Python into C++. This wouldn't be trivial, but is probably possible, although you might have a real hard time debugging a plugin that embeds Boost::Python, so you will probably want to write a number of standalone tests before you even try to move such a planner into move_base as a plugin.

I'm not sure from your question if you are also looking for general docs on how to actually write a new planner in just C++, but basically, the docs you need are [pluginlib](http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib) which tells you how to actually expose and load the class you design, and the [nav_core](http://wiki.ros.org/nav_core) docs which tell you the base classes you need to derive from (an instance of a pluginlib loader basically can only load one type of base class). If developing a local planner, there are a number of helper classes in the base_local_planner package for things like odometry or the "latched_xy_controller".

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-06-21**:
Yeah, actually my question is both specifically regarding Python based plubins and generally about writing planners. So thanks for answering both parts. I'll take a look into the docs. Thanks!

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-06-22**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/11521/plans-for-pluginlib-for-python/

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-06-23**:
Thanks, David! Sounds interesting. Complicated but interesting... I'll see what good use I can make of it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would also like to do this, but right now there's no way to do it. The problem would be sending the entire costmap to the python node. For the global planner, that may be possible, but for the local planner, there may be bandwidth problems.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-06-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-06-19**:
I've considered rewriting the whole thing in Python, but that's probably not productive. :-P

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-06-19**:
If writing a planner in Python is a priority, open a ticket.

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-06-19**:
I see, I see... Well, no, it's not a priority. It'd be just a little more convenient. C++ is on my lists of pretty well known languages. It's just that I like Python a lot more. Anyway, thanks for the insight!